# Object deallocates when called multiple times

Tags: ios, swift, dealloc

I pushing a viewcontroller onto the navigation stack. When I press the back button and re-enter the same page multiple times, the object in the initializer gets de-allocated. Here is my code:

```
init(url: NSURL) {
    super.init(nibName: "CustomUIWebView", bundle: nil)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.setValue(kHeaderObject, forHTTPHeaderField: "headerTestField")
    urlRequest = request
}

public convenience init(testURL: NSURL) {
    self.init(url: testURL)
}

required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

The crash happens on `request.setValue("", forHTTPHeaderField: "headerTestField")`

This is the error message I receive:

> -[CFString retain]: message sent to deallocated instance

Any idea on whats going wrong with my code?
I call the method inside didSelectCell delegate method of the table view in the previous view.

```
TestViewController *tvc = [[TestViewController alloc] initWithTestURL:testURL];
```

`kHeaderObject` is declared as `extern NSString *kHeaderObject;`
If I replace it with the string directly hardcoded I don't see this crash. I wonder why accessing static memory should matter.

*Constants.h*

```
extern NSString *k_strOfferingIdValueHeader;
```

*Constants.m*

```
#import "Constants.h"

NSString *kHeaderObject = @"test123";
```

`Constants.h` is added to the bridging header file.

`kHeaderObject` is updated once on app launch in application delegate.

Comment: I don't see any problems in the code you posted. Can you post the complete, symbolicated stack trace?

Comment: Can you post more code, please? Where is `kHeaderObject` declared in relation to your code? What is the signature of the class that has the constructors in your post?

Comment: I have narrowed the issue to `request.setValue(kHeaderObject, forHTTPHeaderField: "headerTestField")` where is static extern but not a constant. If I update the variable to be a `const` and not update it in the application delegate the crash doesn't happen. The static variable seems to have a reference count of -1 in swift.

Comment: Any update to this ?